# jquery: Заменить телефон вида "+79106563211" на номер "+7910.....11"

Tags: jquery

Есть список телефонных номеров по 12 символов:

```html
<div class='tel'>+79106563211</div>
<div class='tel'>+79106563212</div>
<div class='tel'>+79106563213</div>
```

Задачи:

1. При загрузке страницы нужно заменить в них символы с 6 по 10 на точки, вот так: "+7910.....11"

Я сделал так:

```js
  $('document').ready(function(){
   var text = $('.tel').text();
   var text_1 = text.substr(0,3); // подстрока 1
   var text_2 = text.substr(-2,2); // подстрока 2
   
   var mascText = text_1+'........'+text_2; // формирование маски
   
   $('.tel').hide(); // скрыть телефон
   $('.tel').parent().append('<div class="masc"></div>');
   $('.tel').parent().find('.masc').html(mascText); // помещение маски в новый div
  })
```

Но тогда во все div class="masc" добавляется последний телефонный номер с div class="tel", а мне нужно, каждый div.masc содержал свой уникальный номер

2. При клике по классу 'tel' подставлять вместо номера с точками полный номер, вот так: "+79106563211"

Я сделал так:

```js
$('.masc').click(function(){ // при клике по маске
  $('.tel').hide(); // скрыть все телефоны
  $('.masc').show(); // показать все маски
  $(this).hide(); // скрыть текущую маску
  $(this).parent().find('.tel').show(); // показать текущий телефон 
})
```

Работает правильно.

Подскажите варианты решения моей задачи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант записать телефон в атрибут, например `data-tel`. При загрузке поменять текст на короткий номер и при клике менять текст на тот что в атрибуте.

```js
$('.tel').each(function(elem) {
  var text_1 = $(this).data('tel').substr(0,5); // подстрока 1
  var text_2 = $(this).data('tel').substr(-2,2); // подстрока 2
  $(this).text(text_1 + '...' + text_2);
});

$('.tel').click(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).data('tel'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tel' data-tel='+79106563211'></div>
<div class='tel' data-tel='+79106563211'></div>
<div class='tel' data-tel='+79106563211'></div>
```